# Django - using different apps together in a project

Tags: django, django-templates, django-views, django-apps

In the basic Django tutorials and documentations I have found so far, apps are treated as some standalone parts of the project.
I haven't yet found, though, solutions of using them together in a complex project.

We can sign up at some url `domain/signup`, and it is handled by `users.views.signup`.

- For a GET request `signup` renders `signup.html`.
- For a POST request, after evaluating the posted data, it either
  renders `signup.html`  with some message or registers a new user,
  logs him/her in and redirects somewhere.

We can create a new post at `domain/new_post` (or `domain/user/new_post`), which is handled by `posts.views.new_post`. It acts similarly to the `signup` handler:

- For a GET request it renders `new_post.html`.
- For POST requests it evaluates post data and then either renders
  `new_post.html` with messages or registers the new post and redirects
  somewhere.

A general website is built up of several apps, and the webpage displayed for a request at some url offers functionalities from several apps.
For example, after logging into some popular social site, we can create new entries on our wall, search users (it is normally a wider search, but for sake of simplicity, let's only deal with users), also ads and our friends may be listed in the sidebars.

**How are these parts built up from the different views and templates of the different apps?**
To make the question more specific:

- For a GET request received at some url, how can we display
  user-search-form, new-post-form and friends-list together?
  If we do that by some project-level common view, what about the app-level views?
  I have read that the `{% include %}` tag is handy for building template from several "subtemplates", but what about the different variables the included templates take?
- How can we handle user-search-related GET requests, and new-post-related POST requests that may be sent from the same url?
  (The expression "requests sent from urls" may be inappropriate, but the user may send the different requests by acting on the page displayed at one specific url.)
- Also, the different components should be kept decoupled.

*Note: this question may be too generic for SO, so instead of detailed answers I would also appreciate sources, possibly with examples of using different apps together "in action".*

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> For a GET request received at some url, how can we display
>   user-search-form, new-post-form and friends-list together?

You can request to render any template from any view.  Django will search for the template through every registered app for a `template` directory.  Or you can specify your own template directories using `TEMPLATE_DIR`, but it seems like you already knew this from your next question....

> If we do that by some project-level common view, what about the
>   app-level views?

Could you please try to explain this question in more depth?

> I have read that the {% include %} tag is handy for building template
>   from several "subtemplates", but what about the different variables
>   the included templates take?

From the [docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/templates/builtins/#include):

> An included template is rendered with the context of the template
>   that’s including it.

If you have a partial template, intended for including, like:

```
# hello.html
<h2>Hello {{ person.name }}</h2>
```

and another template is including it:

```
# greeting.html
{% include 'hello.html' %}


render_to_response('greeting.html', {})
```

the output will be `Hello` because you do not have a `person` in the template context

I don't quite understand your second bullet point.  Your django package is just a python package.  If you had two apps you can import code any way you choose, importing modules from your two different apps.

For example, in most projects I end up having a `common` app.  This usually contains utilities used throughout the whole django project.  It usually contains my base test classes.

In your apps you can just import

`from yourproject.common.utils import a_function`

To help with decoupling django provides a [signals](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/signals/) framework.  Your apps can emit and receive signals.

> Django includes a “signal dispatcher” which helps allow decoupled
>   applications get notified when actions occur elsewhere in the
>   framework. In a nutshell, signals allow certain senders to notify a
>   set of receivers that some action has taken place. They’re especially
>   useful when many pieces of code may be interested in the same events.

Comment: "If we do that by some project-level common view, what about the app-level views?" --> In the app "posts", we define a create_post() view, which renders post_form.html with optional context variable error_msg. This error_msg is defined in create_post() if some validation fails. If I render post_form.html from a view other than the app's create_post(), I need to do the validation in that view as well, otherwise the template would never get an error_msg variable.

Comment: Why would I render `post_form.html` from some other view? When I use the app in a project, e.g. a social blog, then a user account would be handled by a `user_account()` view. And I'd like to place the rendered `post_form` in some part of the user account page, e.g. in the sidebar.

Comment: As for the second bullet point.. I send a GET request to `www.mysite.com/myaccount/`. The related view (let's say `myaccount()`) returns a page with two form html elements: `user_search` and `new_post`. The first one would operate on the `users` app, the second one on the `posts` app. What view should I apply as `myaccount()`? Shall I define it in one of the two apps; or in a third app? How can this one view handle the two form submits related to two different apps?