# Can i create the same app multiple times in django?

Tags: python, django

I've created a fully functioning blog application in django . But i want to create multiple blogs like i can create multiple posts on blog. How to approach this problem?

Comment: You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15372251/django-using-different-apps-together-in-a-project) may solve your issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you cannot have multiple Django apps of the same name. But, much like you’d have a `Post` model for a singular blog you can create a `Blog` table and have each `Post` have a foreign key to the `Blog` that post belongs to.

Answer (score 0):

You can just have a one a app per django project beacuse we should import `view.py` and `models.py` and `urls.py` and ... in your some files !